# how to override chef attributes with json input file

Tags: chef-infra

```
default[‘cookbook’][‘var_name’]=‘tst1234’
```

now at chef client run, I want to override this value that is passed via json/yaml file using

```
chef-client -zr 'recipe[cookbook]' -j test.json
```

such that `var_name` created on node will have value `qst1234`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

in the `test.json` file, provide the attributes as follows:

```
{
  "normal": {
    "cookbook": {
      "var_name": "qst1234"
    }
  }
}
```

see *all attributes are normal attributes* in [chef-client cli documentation](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client/)